# How To Subscribe To New Posts - Angular

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

I have this post-list.component.ts:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Location } from '../post.model';
import { PostsService } from '../posts.service';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-post-list',
    templateUrl: './post-list.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./post-list.component.css'],
})
export class PostListComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    model: Location[] = [];

    constructor(private http: HttpClient, public postsService: PostsService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        // this.postsService.getPosts().subscribe((res) => {
        //  this.model = res;
        // });

        this.http.get<any>('http://localhost:8000/location').subscribe((res) => {
            this.model = res.location;
        });

        //this.showPosts();
    }

    showPosts() {
        this.postsService.getPosts().subscribe((res) => {
            this.model = res.location;
        });

        console.log(
            this.postsService.getPosts().subscribe((res) => {
                this.model = res;
            })
        );
    }

    onShow(_token: string) {
        var find = this.model.find(({ token }) => token === _token);

        this.postsService.setLat(find.lat);
        this.postsService.setLng(find.lng);

        console.log(
            this.postsService.getLat() + '    ' + this.postsService.getLng()
        );
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {}
}
```

And this post-list.component.html

```
<mat-accordion multi="true" *ngIf="model.length > 0">
  <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let post of model">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      {{ post.token }}
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <p>{{ post.lat }}</p>
    <p>{{ post.lng }}</p>
    <mat-action-row>
      <button mat-raised-button color="accent" (click)="onShow(post.token)">
        GET COORDS
      </button>
    </mat-action-row>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
<p class="info-text mat-body-1" *ngIf="model.length <= 0">No posts added yet</p>
```

The problem is that the data that comes from the database isn't updating without a page refresh.
The problem is that I get the data from DB on ngOnInit() method which is called only on init.
How can I modify the ngOnInit() method to subscribe to the data that comes from database?

The posts.service.ts I tried to work on is that:

```
import { Location } from './post.model';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject, Observable, Subscription, from } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class PostsService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    model: Location[] = [];

    private lat;
    private lng;

    getPosts() {
        return this.http.get<any>('http://localhost:8000/location');
    }

    setLat(lat) {
        this.lat = lat;
    }
    setLng(lng) {
        this.lng = lng;
    }
    getLat() {
        return this.lat;
    }
    getLng() {
        return this.lng;
    }
}
```

But I got no working results.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: You cannot subscribe to your database as such. You need to either poll or use a SignalR style mechanism to push updates to your client. Even then you will not be notified if your database is modified by another application.

Comment: The http call calls your api to get data from your database. It isn't directly connected to it to get updates. You either need to rely on socket communication or to use polling to make additional http call over time

Comment: You want to see DB changes in "real time", without refreshing the page ? With CRUD operations, it won't be possible. One time, we have to do something like that, and we use  a timer job for that (httpget each 20 seconds).

Comment: @CirrusMinor That's a good idea, I'm gonna search how to implement it. And yes, that is what i wanna do. Thanks for your idea!

Comment: @GérômeGrignon Thank for you idea sir, I will search for it!

Comment: for real time updates, search 'chat angular socket' on google. You'll find good tutorials with a chat example.

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule load locations at a certain interval of time (for example one second).

```
mySubscription: Subscription;

ngOnInit() {
    this.mySubscription = interval(1000).subscribe(() => {
        this.loadLocation();
    });
}


loadLocation() {
    this.http.get<any>('http://localhost:8000/location').subscribe((res) => {
        this.model = res.location;
    });
}
```

Comment: That's the right idea but it should be `this.mySubscription = interval(1000).pipe(map(() 
 => this.http.get('http://localhost:8000/location')).subscribe(...)`